# 1px hairline in Photoshop after scaling a selection (feather is set to 0px)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

After some upgrade of Photoshop CC (from PS CC 2017 to 2018 I guess) I noticed 1px hairline on images after scaling a selection. Anti-aliasing is turned off for selection borders and Feather is set to 0px as on the screenshot below. The first image is just a selection. After scaling selection down by squeezing from the top (**Edit > Transform > Scale**) a 1px hairline appears right on the bottom border of the selection. Obviously it can be edited, but if the file is big and has lots of details it could take a while. Also PS CC 2015/2016/2017 wasn't doing that until relatively recent time as I was using this tool before without any issues. Any settings can be changes to restore the original behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the top options bar you'll see `Interpolation` property: make sure it's set to `Bilinear`.

`Bicubic` (the default one) adds additional post-processing (sharpening) that may cause various artifacts on a transparency border. On the left `Bicubic` interpolation, on the right the same transformation with `Bilinear` interpolation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are artifacts that may happen each time you squeeze pixels. As you write, you can easily edit this, but probably the best solution is to crop the image to the desired size.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2221279

Comment: No, unfortunately cropping is not an option. This image was selected just to show the issue - hairline against plain background. I was using scaling of a selection in architecture photography to correct visual appearance of buildings after perspective correction. It's called graduated scaling when you are doing a series of scalings each time with smaller selection. Also there shouldn't be any artifacts as the image has the same pisel color on both sides of the selection. It was introduced in PS just recently.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed it that too.

The soluction I am using is:

Make a selection then make a copy  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>J</kbd> .

Scale the copy.

I use **bicubic interpolation** but you can try the other ones.

See the image below.

[image]